# python assert fires with -O

Tags: python, assert

I am trying to make sure that an assert is not executed by python when using -O. My test program however indicates that it is always executed. I specifically use -O on the command line and I used -O when I ran setup.py with both build and install. Before I submit a bug report I wanted to make sure I did not do any rookie mistakes...

So do I need to do something else or different so that the assert is *not* executed?

My simple script:

```
print __debug__

if __debug__:
    print "True branch"
else:
    print "False branch"

assert(False)
```

works when run standalone. Prints:

```
False
False branch
```

When I copy this snippet in the main program (that I cannot include here...) I get:

```
False
True branch
AssertionError
```

I am utterly confused how that can come about. This Python 2.7.6 on a Mac. (Sorry about the Mac, I have to use it for work.)

Comment: You use `-O` when you run the actual program. Say your program was called `Script.py`, in the command line you would say `Python -O Script.py`

Comment: post some code, preferably [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org)

Comment: The `-O` flag **does** discard assertions. You must be running a prelimary script, and not the final one, with `-O`.

Comment: It sounds as though you're running a `something.pyc` file with the `-O` flag.  You don't want to do that.

Comment: I am a rookie. Can you elaborate what should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve the effect you describe by running a `.pyc` file *directly* with the `-O` flag.  That's an abuse of the way things are supposed to work.  You want to either:

1. Run the `.py` file with or without the `-O` flag (the usual approach), or
2. Run the `.pyc` file *without* the `-O` flag, or
3. Run the `.pyo` file *with* the `-O` flag.

If you run a `.pyc` file with the `-O` flag, or a `.pyo` file without it, you're going to get surprises like this one.

What's happening is that at compile time the peephole optimiser has optimised away the `if __debug__` branches, so the `.pyc` or `.pyo` files will execute the appropriate branch unconditionally.  Then when you run with the wrong `-O` specification, you'll be running with a value of `__debug__` that doesn't match the optimisation that was applied at compile time.

There was a [similar issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue8379) reported on the Python issue tracker a while back, though that was the opposite situation: someone running a `.pyo` file without using the `-O` flag.

A quick example:  suppose I've got a file somewhat like yours named "debug_example.py" sitting in my current directory:

```
noether:Desktop mdickinson$ cat debug_example.py
def main():
    print "__debug__ is {}".format(__debug__)
    if __debug__:
        print "__debug__ is True"
    else:
        print "__debug__ is False"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If we execute the file directly, with or without the `-O` flag, we see the expected results:

```
noether:Desktop mdickinson$ python2 debug_example.py
__debug__ is True
__debug__ is True
noether:Desktop mdickinson$ python2 -O debug_example.py
__debug__ is False
__debug__ is False
```

Now let's compile this file to a "debug_example.pyc" file using the handy [`py_compile`](http://docs.python.org/library/py_compile.html) module.  (In your case this compilation is likely being performed as part of the `setup.py` installation.):

```
noether:Desktop mdickinson$ python2 -m py_compile debug_example.py
noether:Desktop mdickinson$ ls -l debug_example.pyc
-rw-r--r--  1 mdickinson  staff  350 24 Mar 21:41 debug_example.pyc
```

Now we execute the `debug_example.pyc` file, but (wrongly) using the `-O` flag, and Python gets confused:

```
noether:Desktop mdickinson$ python2 -O debug_example.pyc
__debug__ is False
__debug__ is True
```

We can use [Python's `dis` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) to see the bytecode inside the module:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 18 2013, 15:12:51) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import debug_example
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(debug_example)
Disassembly of main:
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('__debug__ is {}')
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (format)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (__debug__)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 PRINT_ITEM          
             13 PRINT_NEWLINE       

  4          14 LOAD_CONST               2 ('__debug__ is True')
             17 PRINT_ITEM          
             18 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             19 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note that there's no bytecode corresponding to the `if` statement there at all: we see an unconditional printing of `'__debug__ is True'`.

Solution: don't execute the `.pyc` or the `.pyo` files directly: execute the `.py` file and let Python figure out whether to use the `.pyc` or `.pyo` as appropriate.

Comment: I am being accused of executing .pyc and .pyo files. My problem is I do not know how to avoid that if I am indeed guilty. In the directory I am running from there is no .pyc or .pyo only the .py. And I am specifying the .py. Of course I have indeed modules compiled and installed with distutils. However I assumed that by running with -O on those compiles I get the correct compilation. Still utterly confused how to compile without the asserts.

Comment: Has any part of the distutils install removed the .py files, leaving only the .pyc files?  That could be the cause of your problem.  Or do you have .py files next to all your .pyc files?  If the latter, is it possible that those .py files are unreadable for some reason (permissions, etc.)?  *Somehow*, it looks very much as though Python is failing to find the .py file for a module and is picking up the .pyc file instead.

Comment: BTW, I wasn't accusing you of anything: just showing one situation (and the only one I can think of) where you might see the effects you describe.  If the answer isn't helpful I'll happily delete it.

Comment: Another possibility you could look into is that your .pyc files have somehow been renamed to .pyo, or vice versa.  Without more information on your setup it's really difficult to tell.  Can you cut down to a reproducible example?

Comment: I will try to reproduce on a smaller example. So far what I see is that distutils creates a so called .egg file. I think that is what has the modules I am loading. Maybe an out of date egg file is in the way. The .pyc files are not around anymore when the program is run.

Comment: Btw, your comment was helpful, I was trying to be funny.

Comment: Solved. I will accept your answer, since it lead me to figure out what is going on. Distutils has its own way of managing the compilation. Since I cannot put code in the comment here, I will edit the question. Please advise if I should have answered my own question instead.

Comment: Sure, answering your own question could work (and I'll upvote it if you do).  I'm very interested to know what the cause was!

Comment: I am about to give up on this. I could not figure out how to run optimized code with python under my circumstances, more on the below. I accept the above answer, since it is helpful for the vanilla case.

However, when running on OSX and one uses distutils or setuptools to compile and then one runs the created module with nosetests, it is not clear to me how to make sure that the optimized code runs. I tried everything I could think of and I understood from the documentations, but still the testing assert I added fires.