# Python's __debug__ special variable not working for an imported module

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I make the special variable `__debug__` in python work for modules which have been installed with `python setup.py install` and then imported?

Currently, I am working on a package which has the following statement in a function:

```
     ...
     if __debug__:
         print "HERE", __debug__
     ...
```

When I import the package in a program that I run with `python -OO file.py`, and call a function which eventually calls **this** function, I see in stdout:

```
HERE False
HERE False
HERE False
...
```

So this makes me think that `if __debug__:` was converted to `if True:` separate of the `__debug__` variable being defined on import.

Therefore, I have also tried installing the package with `python -OO setup.py install`, but this did not fix the issue either. I am able to see the expected behavior of `__debug__` when I use `if __debug__:` in a standalone file and execute it with optimization, but not when I import it.

**How can I make the `__debug__` variable work for imported modules?**

Comment: This question may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22619681/270986

Comment: Do you not have the `.py` files installed?

Comment: Thanks, @MarkDickinson, I will check it out. On first glance it may be a different problem but I'm not sure yet.

Comment: @user2357112, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Does your installed package only have the `.pyc` file for this module, without the corresponding `.py`?

Comment: @user2357112, when I print `bifrost.__file__`, it does look like it was byte-compiled, for I get: `bifrost/__init__.pyc`. Do you know how I can force installation without byte-compiling?

Comment: Alternatively, a way to run `python setup.py install` with optimization turned on would also answer this question

Comment: It looks like the `-O2` flag might be a way to do it for `setup.py`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the help in the comment section. It finally worked out - running:

```
python setup.py --help install
```

showed a list of options. Then, it became apparent I was installing with optimization incorrectly. I needed to run:

```
python setup.py install -O2
```

to turn on optimizations when compiling my module. On the question that @MarkDickinson posted: [python assert fires with -O](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22619681/270986), it turns out that byte-compiling a module actually sets up the `if __debug__:` statements beforehand, meaning that `__debug__` did in fact get redefined later with no effect on the `if` block.

An alternate option is to install with:

```
python setup.py install --no-compile
```

which should leave everything as is so you can redefine `__debug__`.